# ORA-00979 Not a group by expression?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the following code which throws an exception

> Ora-00979: Not a group by expression.

Even if I remove the `group by` clause it still gives error

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.

I am new in this field and do not have enough knowledge about joins etc. I'll appreciate if someone please help me with the following query.

```
select sDateTime AS Sale_Date, SUM(Amount) AS Sale, SerName 
FROM SALES natural join sales_Description natural join Services 
where ((sDateTime >= to_date('2015-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd')) 
  and (sDateTime <= to_date('2015-01-09','yyyy-MM-dd'))) 
  GROUP BY to_char(sDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Comment: `GROUP BY sDateTime ,SerName` That natural JOIN will byte you in the a@@ sooner or later in case some changes the column names

Comment: why to_char and not sDateTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error `not a group by` is due to the following -

`GROUP BY to_char(sDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd'),`.

You need to either have the same `to_char` in `select` or change the `group by` to `sDateTime`.

The second time you get the error `not a single-group group` error because you removed group by expression. You need to have the `columns` of the `select list` for which you are `aggregating` the rows.

Try the following -

```
    SELECT to_char(sDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS       Sale_Date, 
SerName, 
SUM(Amount) AS Sale
       FROM SALES natural join sales_Description natural join Services 
     WHERE ((sDateTime >= to_date('2015-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd')) 
      AND (sDateTime <= to_date('2015-01-09','yyyy-MM-dd'))) 
       GROUP BY to_char(sDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd'), SerName
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SerName` column is not included in the `GROUP BY` clause. You have to include it in the `GROUP BY` clause or aggregate it (`MAX`, `MIN`, etc).

Try to change your query to this:

```
SELECT sDateTime AS Sale_Date, SUM(Amount) AS Sale, SerName 
FROM SALES natural join sales_Description natural join Services 
WHERE ((sDateTime >= to_date('2015-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd')) 
  AND (sDateTime <= to_date('2015-01-09','yyyy-MM-dd'))) 
GROUP BY to_char(sDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd'), SerName
```

Anyway, I don't know if that's the result you want.

Comment: This is incorrect as expressions in group by and select do not match. Query should either change select or the group by condition. finally the correct query should be 
`SELECT to_char(sDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS       Sale_Date, 
SerName, 
SUM(Amount) AS Sale
       FROM SALES natural join sales_Description natural join Services 
     WHERE ((sDateTime >= to_date('2015-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd')) 
      AND (sDateTime <= to_date('2015-01-09','yyyy-MM-dd'))) 
       GROUP BY to_char(sDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd'), SerName`